# Cytoscape with Haystack or Bezier Layout: How to Shorten Edge Length

Tags: cytoscape.js

I am new to Cytoscape, and I have a working graph, but my nodes are very far apart.  While I realize Cytoscape generates everything dynamically, it seems like it should be possible to say "use half as much space between nodes".

This demo:

http://js.cytoscape.org/demos/2ebdc40f1c2540de6cf0

seems to show that you can dynamically change the lengths of edges.  However, when I look at the source code (https://gist.github.com/maxkfranz/2ebdc40f1c2540de6cf0), I can't figure out how it works.

It seems like the demo is passing a `edgeLength` option to `makeLayout`, but the Cytoscape documentation doesn't even mention `edgeLength` as a valid option.

Can anyone more experienced with Cytoscape point me to how I can shorten the edges between my nodes?

Answer (score -1):

Each layout is different, and the combination of values you use depends on what effect you're trying to create.

- Force-directed layouts usually have a weight that affects edge length by spring forces.
- In general, the bounding box can affect the length.
- Some layouts have spacing adjustment multipliers.
- Some layouts have other, miscellaneous options that affect edge length.

You have to look at the options for the layout you're interested in and experiment with them to get the effect you're looking for.  That holds true for every layout for every graph theory lib, Cytoscape included.

Comment: Saying "there are lots of answers, but I'm not going to actually give you any specific one" is not an answer.  Plus I was specifically asking about Bezier and/or Haystack, and you didn't even mention either.

Comment: I iterated over the major classes of layouts and the types of options that you should pay particular attention to.  *Every* option in a layout affects node position, and naturally node position directly affects edge length.  You will have to carefully read the documentation for each option in the layouts you're interested in, and decide what combination of options and values works best for you.

Comment: If you're not familiar with the geometry involved w.r.t. point (i.e. node) positions affecting line (i.e. edge) length, Wikipedia has good articles on the [Pythagorean Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem) and [Bezier curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve).

Comment: I think you're over-complicating this.  There are N inputs/arguments for any Cystoscape graph.  In the case of Bezier, N=4 (`control-point-step-size`, `control-point-distance`, `control-point-weight`, `edge-distances`).  Of those N, only a subset actually control how far one dot gets rendered from another dot (eg. `control-point-step-size` doesn't appear to be relevant, so subsetN = 3).  I'd accept an answer that simply explained how those three simple inputs relate, so that when when I render a Bezier graph, I can know what effect each arg will have on the dot distance.